# Change C-z from Minimise to Toggle Evil Mode

Tags: key-bindings, evil

I am a fairly new emacs user and would appreciate any help you could offer.

I have recently installed the evil mode package onto my emacs. The package itself works perfectly, however, the default toggle binding `C-z` is not working as expected. When outside of evil mode it minimises the current frame. If I invoke evil mode through `M-x RET evil-mode` then input `C-z`, it will toggle back as expected.

I have attempted a fix by adding the following to my init.el file in an attempt to overwrite the existing key binding:

```lisp
(setq evil-toggle-key "C-z")
(require 'evil)
```

I have also tried

```lisp
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-z"))
```

alone and in conjunction with the previous but this seems to completely unbind the key chord.

Does anyone have a solution which changes `C-z` from 'minimise frame' to 'toggle evil mode'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of those works - just unbind the global key first.

```lisp
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-z"))
(require 'evil)
(setq evil-toggle-key "C-z")
(evil-mode 1)
```

Until `evil-mode` is activated, the key binding does not work.   I assume you have `evil-mode` started by default, so the above should suit your workflow.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is perfect. I was not expecting to have got so close to the solution before posting.